# Trigger to throw an error for community users when clicked on few stages in opportunity path-how?

Tags: trigger, community

[image]

-------Trigger-----------

```
trigger stageNames on Opportunity (before insert) {
         if (Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {
             //List<String> stageNames = new List<String>();
             List<String> results= new List<String>();
             HTTP http = new HTTP();
            HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
            HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
            //System.debug(response.getBody());
            req.setMethod('GET'); 
            req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v43.0/ui-api/object-info/Opportunity/picklist-values/0126F0000022AbK/StageName');
            response = http.send(req);
            System.debug(response.getBody());
            String json = response.getBody();
            JSON2Apex uv= JSON2Apex.parse(json);
            system.debug('json deserialised '+uv.values);
            for(JSON2Apex.values val: uv.values )
            {
                system.debug(val.value);
                results.add(val.value);
            }
             Id profileId=userinfo.getProfileId();//UserInfo.getUserType()
             String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:profileId].Name;
             system.debug('ProfileName'+profileName); 
             if(profileName == 'Customer Community User') 
             {

             }
         }

    }
```

When the community user logs in he needs to click the stages until Verification but when he clicks on Documents Review stage the trigger should throw an error.The internal user can be able to click on all the stages.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Id profileId=userinfo.getProfileId();
String profileName=[Select Id,Name from Profile where Id=:profileId].Name;
system.debug('ProfileName'+profileName);

Comment: I could get the profile name through apex class

Comment: @vshah , So you are trying to fire a ERROR message if anyone selects "Documents Review" from you Stage field in the opportunity page layout? Is that what you are asking?

Comment: yes but based on profile.I mean when community user selects "Documents Review" stage in the path shown in above pic i need to throw an error message but when internal user selects the same stage it should not throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this you shouldn't use Apex, you could use a validation rule:

```
AND( 
ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Document Review"), 
$Profile.Id ="00e1t000001P8E6" 
)
```

Using this validation rule will stop the user with that Profile.Id to change to that stage. Just copy this formula and change the Profile.Id to the Profile that you want to block this stage option. You can have multiple ids or other logic.
This Validation Rule should be create on the opportunity object.

[Here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/validation_rules) there is information on how to create a validation rule.

Comment: without providing profile id directly $Profile.Id ="00e1t000001P8E6" like this can i fetch the profile id based on login in validation rule

Comment: Can you tell me why do you want to do some kind of dynamic entry for that value? What is the business reason? Who shouldn't be allowed to make that change on the Stage field?

Comment: community users should not be able to select Documents Review stage but internal users can select all the stages. So how can i do that.

Comment: Get the "Customer Community User" id in your Org and past it to the` $Profile.Id ="HERE"`